# [Regex]: Add sonar projects using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a list of projects:

- diagnostics-nodejs
- documentdb-client-nodeJS
- gherkin-runner-nodejs
- openid-client-nodejs-useless
- azure-blob-storage-client-nodejs
- azure-sql-client-nodejs
- CPNodeJS
- appmon-oneagent-linux-nodejs-useless
- kafkaConsumerProducerBench
- sample-publish-kafka-nodeJS
- starter-kit-nestjs

And I need to add them to my portfolio in SonarQube 6.7 using Regex ( as it's displayed below )

[image: Onar add project Regex]

I'm using this regex: `.*nodejs` This only adds projects ending with nodejs but the rest is not added ( documentdb-client-nodeJS , CPNodeJS, kafkaConsumerProducerBench , nestjs).

Any ideas please on a regex to add all the projects.

#### Edit:

I don't have admin access to the sonarQube. I can't access Sonar config nor install new plugins. I can only edit the regex to add my projects!

Comment: Important! I just figured out that regex in SonarQube are based on Javascript regex. Not only that But it also doesn't accept flags ( like i, g ...)  So all the answers below are incorrect

Answer (score -1):

To match all put

```
.*
```

The regex engine is case sensitive. You need to specify without case sensitivity. You also have a file that doesn't contain the string `nodejs` but has `nestjs`. The below will capture both

```
(?i)nodejs|(?i)nestjs
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use the case insensitive options (?i)nodejs. and then add the other 2 projects that are left.

```
(?i)nodejs|(?i)starter-kit-nestjs|(?i)kafkaConsumerProducerBench
```

Here's a [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IFFKeE/2)

Comment: it is enough to specify `(?i)` only once, on the beginning of regex. Anyhow, good answer